# Laravel - Datatable with post method show raw data instead of table

Tags: php, laravel, post, datatable

i have an audit trails report to show the data based on range of date, selected by user. So user will select the range in page (audits) and when click submit will redirect to page (audits_view).

I want to show the data in datatables, but in audits_view, the result that i get is only raw data like this

```
{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":490,"recordsFiltered":490,"data":[{"id":144586,"event":"created","created_at":"2021-05-19 10:28:50.660","auditable_type":"App\\Model\\Loglogin","user":null},{"id":144585,"event":"created","created_at":"2021-05-19
```

here is the audits_view blade and controller

```
       <table id="user_table" class="table table-bordered data-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="35%">auditable_type</th>
                        <th width="35%">event</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
         </table>
          
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#user_table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "{{url('/')}}/report/audits",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            'data': function ( d ) {
                d._token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
        },
        
        columns: [
            {
                data: 'auditable_type',
                name: 'auditable_type'
            },
            {
                data: 'event',
                name: 'event'
            },
        ]
    });
  });
</script>
```

here is the controller

```
public function audits_view(Request $request)
    {
        $this->authorize('view_audit_trails');
        $user = Auth::user();
        $date1= $request->input('date1');
        $date2= $request->input('date2');

        $data = \OwenIt\Auditing\Models\Audit::with('user')
          ->select(['id', 'event', 'created_at', 'auditable_type'])
          ->whereDate('created_at','>=',$date1)>whereDate('created_at','<=',$date2)->get();
           
        return DataTables::of($data)
            ->make(true);
              
        return view('report.audits_view', compact('date1','date2','user'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is just basic idea:

The view function should be like this:

```
public function audits_view(Request $request) {
        $this->authorize('view_audit_trails');
        $user = Auth::user();
        $date1= $request->input('date1');
        $date2= $request->input('date2');
        return view('report.audits_view', compact('date1','date2','user'));
}
```

and for data table you should create new post route and on that route the function should be like this:

```
 public function audits_data(Request $request) {
        $date1= $request->input('date1');
        $date2= $request->input('date2');
        
        $data = \OwenIt\Auditing\Models\Audit::with('user')
      ->select(['id', 'event', 'created_at', 'auditable_type'])
      ->whereDate('created_at','>=',$date1)>whereDate('created_at','<=',$date2);
       
    return DataTables::of($data)
        ->make(true);
}
```

the js should be something like this:

```
$('#user_table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "{{url('/')}}/report/audits",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: function ( d ) {
                d._token = "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                d.date1 = $('#date1').val(),
                d.date2 = $('#date2').val(),
        },
        
        columns: [
            {
                data: 'auditable_type',
                name: 'auditable_type'
            },
            {
                data: 'event',
                name: 'event'
            },
        ]
    });
```